# iis 7 asp.net deployment problems

Tags: windows

I am trying to run an asp.net website in a windows iis7 locally(I am trying to create an intranet for my site)  on  machine that is going to be running the site for an intranet. I seem to get the following message:

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I was getting a message stating the the runtime for one of my bootstraps assembly was built in a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. I have tried to Google search this but was met by a 404 page error from Google. I have no clue how to resolve this issue any help with this would be appreciated.

My asp.net project is referencing .net framework 4.5.1

Comment: Make sure your Application pool is set to `.NET CLR Version v4.0`, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0 suggests you are using v2.0

Comment: thanks that was one of the problems I had I had to deselect the 3.5.1 in the add remove features window.